Reordering author name in bibliography
I'm doing my bibliography with LaTeX (Overleaf), which is in alphabetical order. In this bibliography, I have references to websites which have, in place of the author name, the name of the institution. Overleaf uses the last word of the institution's name as a family name, and reorder it alphabetically in the bibliography according to this name:

This turns into:

I would like to keep the words in the institution's name in the right order and that it shows at the right place in the bibliogaphy.
How can I do that?

If you're using biblatex, try the following: Specify the author with braces (as in author={{DCMI Usage Board}} and/or add a sortkey = {DCMI Usage Board}.

The double braces worked perfectly, thank you!

Assuming you use biblatex, wrap the author field content inside an additional pair of braces to avoid the sorting procedure from splitting out first/last names:
@article{DCMI_2021,
  title   = {Dublin CoreTM Metadata Element Set, Version 1.1: Reference Description},
  url     = {https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dces/},
  journal = {Dublincore},
  author  = {{DCMI Usage Board}},
  year    = {2012}
}

Also see section 2.3.3 Corporate authors and editors (p 35 in the biblatex documentation), where it suggests using the author (with additional braces {...}) and shortauthor fields for use in citations.
